# scrape YouTube home page based on oauth2

Tags: ios, youtube

I am looking solution for scraping my YouTube account from iOS application. I successfully complete oauth2 authentication and can create requests to YouTube API. But I need to scrape some pages, that not available from API. I understand that to do this, I need session cookie for my Google Account. But could not understand how to receive it based on oauth2 credentials.

Could you please help me, no matter what programming language you will use.

Comment: Isn't this against YouTube policy? If it is, you won't be able to put your app on the App Store.

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Thank you, I will ream more about this.